# How to get list of spaces for a specific wiki?

Tags: velocity, xwiki

I would like to get spaces of all wikis I have in my xwiki farm

I wrote this code:

```
#set($WikiManager = $xwiki.wikimanager)
#set($wikiList = $WikiManager.getAllWikis())
$msg.get("wikimanager.totalnumberofwiki") : $wikiList.size()
#if($wikiList.size()!=0)
  #foreach($wiki in $wikiList)
    * *$wiki*

    ## pb in this line below
    #set($spaces = $xwiki.getSpaces())

    <table>
      <tr><th>Spaces</th></tr>
      #foreach ($space in $spaces)
        <tr><td>$space</td></tr>
      #end
    </table>
  #end
#end
```

But this script gives me only the spaces of the current wiki where I execute it.

Do you have an idea how to fix it ?

Thank you for your help.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

You probably should change database:

```
      #set($currentwiki = $xcontext.database)

      $xcontext.setDatabase($wikidoc.wikiName)
```

then change it back:

```
          $xcontext.setDatabase($currentwiki)
```

Answer (score 0):

A said Woolear, you have to switxh database context.
In xwiki syntax 2.0, your code should be :

```
{{velocity}}
#set($currentwiki = $xcontext.database)
#set($WikiManager = $xwiki.wikimanager)
#set($wikiList = $WikiManager.getAllWikis())
$msg.get("wikimanager.totalnumberofwiki") : $wikiList.size()
#if($wikiList.size()!=0)
  #foreach($wiki in $wikiList)
    === $wiki :

    |=Spaces
    ##switch database
    $xcontext.setDatabase($wiki.wikiName)
    #set($spaces = $xwiki.getSpaces())
      #foreach ($space in $spaces)
        |$space
      #end
  #end
#end
$xcontext.setDatabase($currentwiki)
{{/velocity}}
```